# Flask Session loses key values

Tags: python, python-2.7, session, flask, youtube-data-api

I have a trouble with Flask session. It loses values after redirect, here's code I'm using:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    session['permanent'] = True
    return flask.render_template('index.html') ##Here is template with form that passes value via GET to /station

@app.route('/station', methods=['GET'])
def station():      
    if 'st' not in session:
            p = flask.request.args.get('Station', '')
            session['st'] = p
            print session['st']
    if 'credentials' not in session:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(session['credentials'])
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    else:
        ##DO SOME STUFF WITH st and credentials##
        return "Done!"

@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json',scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',redirect_uri=flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True))
    if 'code' not in flask.request.args:
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return flask.redirect(auth_uri)
    else:
        auth_code = flask.request.args.get('code')
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
        session['credentials'] = credentials.to_json()
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('station'))
```

So what happens: Firts browser renders index.html. It's fine, user clicks something and passes the GET param to the station(). It goes thru the:

```
if 'st' not in session
```

session key is being set correctly. I see it in the print. Then user is being redirected to the /oauth2callback. There is whole auth process with youtube api and when script takes user back from /oauth2callback to /station via

```
return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('station'))
```

for some reason code enters the

`if 'st' not in session`
again. Like there was no session['st'] anymore. In the result I don't have the value from the form...
I have no clue what to do. (Using Flask 0.10 and hosting stuff on Heroku)

Comment: Hey did you find a solution. Im having the same issue but on Google App Engine, I'm thinking the way the systems scal and move users around instances it doesn't send the session data because technically its a new session. So my users are being forced to sign in repeatedly.